# Mailboxer rails 4 Custom Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

Hi guys I am currently using the mailboxer gem and am wanting to customize the views for these renders

```
%h2 Inbox
%ul= render mailbox.inbox
%hr 
%h2 Sentbox
%ul= render mailbox.sentbox
%hr 
%h2 Trash
%ul= render mailbox.trash
```

I would like to add a from and a link in the title  of the email but dont know where the view is to edit it or where to generate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server logs. They should be placed in 
`app/views/message_mailer/new_message_email.html.erb`, etc

Comment: This is only for templates being emailed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial for custom [views](http://jamestansley.com/2014/02/22/customizing-the-mailboxer-ruby-gem-2/).

**Controller**

```
def index
  @inbox ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox
end
```

**View**

```
<% @inbox.each do |conversation| %>
  <%= conversation.originator.username%>
  <%= link_to  raw(truncate(strip_tags(conversation.subject), :length => 15)), conversation_path(conversation) %> 
  <%= link_to "", {:controller => "conversations", :action => "trash", :id => conversation.id}, :title=> "Move to Trash", :method=>'post', data: { confirm: '¿Estas seguro?' }, :class=> "btn btn btn-danger icon-remove" %>
  <%= conversation.updated_at%>
<% end %>
```

then create a **show.html.erb** to see the full message.

Here is another [sample app](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app)